# Rigid Balls aligned along a line in vacuum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, momentum, collision

Recently I've been trying to visualize a situation where i have these really rigid identical balls aligned along a line so close to each other in vacuum.Now if I were to apply an impulsive force to the ball at one end of the line,along the line, does the time taken to transfer that momentum to the ball at the other end  depend on the velocity attained by the first ball , immediately after the application of that impulsive force? If no, why? What would be the case if i were to increase the distance between adjacent balls a little more?

Comment: There aren't are perfectly rigid balls in real life. So in reality the impulse take time to travel through the balls.

Answer (score 1):

No the time taken does not depend of the velocity attained by the first ball(if they are ideally rigid) it rather depends on the elasticity or rigidity of the balls. 
So for ideally rigid bodies, the time taken to transfer approaches 0.
Nothing would happen with an increase in distance between the two balls.

See:
[Is the reaction force for a stone hitting a wall infinite?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/220468/is-the-reaction-force-for-a-stone-hitting-a-wall-infinite/220477#220477)

Comment: But isn't this situation kind of analogous to the travelling of disturbance through some medium where you have these rigid molecules instead.In that case how can the speed of transfer of a disturbance be independant on the amplitude of vibration( if say the medium is metal)

Comment: I should think that there are inter-molecular forces acting there, which accounts for the wave like behavior. Here on the other hand, I don't expect to see any periodic parameters.

Comment: What about the propagation of sound through, say an ideal gas,Where they say that speed of transfer of a disturbance is independant of pressure amplitude of that disturbance?

Comment: The speed of propagation is dependent upon the sheer modulus, the coeff of elasticity. So as I said, it is the elasticity that matters.

Comment: Yes I do know that.Let me make myself more clear. If you have this medium of ideal gas, and say you gave an additional momentum to a collection of molecules amoung them by some means(That can be considered to be a disturbance, right?), Would the time taken to transfer that momentum from molecule to molecule depend on the additional velocity you gave? The  answer is obviously, No. But i don't have any idea why.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes my above answer completely invalid. To answer your original question, it indeed depends on the velocity you impart. Plus the distance between the two balls.
I instead was talking about the time taken to transfer momentum once the balls collide.